# Compare pandas series of Dataframe as a Whole and not element wise

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, row

Problem:
Accessing the same column of a Dataframe I would like to compare if series is the same.

Data:

DATA link for copy and paste: API_link_to_data='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenfly/opsd/master/opsd_germany_daily.csv'

energyDF = pd.read_csv(API_link_to_data)

```
row3_LOC  = energyDF.loc[[3],:]
row3_ILOC = energyDF.iloc[[3],:]
```

This code compares element wise

```
 row3_LOC  == row3_ILOC
```

getting a list with booleans

What I would like to get is TRUE, since  row3_LOC and  row3_ILOC are the same

Thanks

Comment: Use: row3_LOC.equals(row3_ILOC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check,both `row3_LOC` and `row3_ILOC` are in turn dataframes.

```
print(type(row3_LOC))
print(type(row3_ILOC))
```

results in:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

You can check if they are equal using `row3_ILOC.equals(row3_LOC)`. Refer to the [equals function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two series using [`all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
(row3_loc == row3_ILOC).all()
```

As soon as one of the values don't match, you will get a false. You may also be interested in [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html#pandas.DataFrame.any), which checks whether at least one value is true.

Answer (score 0):

Fill the Nans with NULL
`energyDF.fillna('NULL')`

```
energyDF = energyDF.fillna('NULL') 
energyDF.loc[[3],:] == (energyDF.iloc[[3],:])

Date    Consumption Wind    Solar   Wind+Solar
3   True    True    True    True    True
```